# Explanation of Statement's Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new to Python, so I was hoping somebody could break down the following statement and explain the purpose of each part.

```
[digit for digit in string.split() if digit.isdigit()][0]
```

Obviously `for digit in string.split()` creates a list of substrings by separating the string into elements at each space.

What confuses me is the `digit` at the very beginning and the `if` statement at the very end.

**Is the very first `digit` what will be returned `if digit.isdigit()`?**

**Why must this statement be wrapped in a list?**

I've never seen a for loop and an if statement combined into one statement like this before, but it reminds me of a particular JS syntax: `for (condition) // whatever` or `if (condition) // whatever`. However, in JS you can't combine them into a single statement (i.e. `for (condition) if (condition) // whatever`).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: This is Python's [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) expression, not a statement. It turns what otherwise would be written with `for` loops and `if` statements into a single expression that evaluates as a list. It isn't necessary to use list comprehension, but it helps to make code more concise and in some cases, easier to read.

Please read the official documentation for more details.

Comment: @blhsing thx buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a list comprehension. You will find plenty of pages explaining how it works. Just ask you favorite search engine.

Comment: thanks. i'm gon go read more about it